# Grape API (swagger doc) - Global configuration of 'desc'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, documentation, swagger, ruby-grape

Its been an interesting an busy week. I am working on a Rails project and included `Grape` to implement the **API**.

The API has 2 sections

- No auth required (no headers)
- Auth required

I setup the app with and all is working...

- Grape
- Grape Swagger
- Grape Swagger Rails

For stating that a header is required I use some thing like this...

```
class ProfilesApi < Grape::API

  resource :profiles do

    desc 'List all profiles' do
      headers Authorization: {
                description: 'Validates identity through JWT provided in auth/login',
                required: true
              }
    end
    get do
      present User.all, with: Presenters::ProfilePresenter
    end
  end
end
```

Now the problem is that I this description in a lot of similar mountable API classes.

Is there a way that can kind of make this common (kind of inherited) so that I don't need to define it wit every Grape method.

```
    desc 'List all profiles' do
      headers Authorization: {
                description: 'Validates identity through JWT provided in auth/login',
                required: true
              }
    end
```

Thanks in advance and hope you guys enjoy the weekend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there's a way. I achieve that by defining a method in `class API` so that it's accessible in everything that inherits from `API`. Something like:

```
module Myapp
  class API < Grape::API
    def self.auth_headers
      { Authorization: { description: 'Validates identity through JWT provided in auth/login',required: true}}
    end
  end
end
```

And you access it like that:

```
desc "List all profiles", {
  headers: Myapp::API.auth_headers
}
```

Of course, there're much more ways but they depend on your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

i think this may be an updated version of grape-api thing, I've had to get this working with :

```
    desc 'My description text' do
       headers Authorization: {description: "pass the access token as Bearer", required: true }
   end
```